# Выборка текущего элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть множество элементов с одним CSS классом. Как выбрать тот элемент, на который нажал посетитель страницы? Пример:

HTML:

```
<div class="class">
<a id="aclass">клик</a>
</div>

<div class="class">
<a id="aclass">клик2</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
        var link = $('.aclass',this).text();
        alert(link);
});
```

Такой код, видимо, неправильный, раз не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `this` для обращения к селектору, на который нажали.

```js
$('.class').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).find('.aclass').text();
    alert(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class">
  <div class="aclass">Link 1</div>
</div>

<div class="class">
  <div class="aclass">Link 2</div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** У вас `aclass` в html указан как `id`, а в js вы пытаетесь получить его как `class`.

Comment: Спасибо работает))) эхх да совсем не заметил =)